# почему не работает функция toFixed(2) в промисе? JS а отдельно работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
fetch("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5")
            .then(function(resp){
                return resp.json()
           })
          .then(function(data){
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          $('.kurs').append(
            '<a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">' +data[i].ccy+ ':' +data[i].buy.toFixed(2)+ '/' +data[i].sale.toFixed(2)+ '</a>')
  // не хочет полученное число 27.70000 переводит в 27.70 Пишет : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data[i].buy.toFixed is not a function
                }
                
                return true;
           });
           
           //Вот так работает
           var usd = 27.70000;
           console.log(usd.toFixed(2));//27,70
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="links kurs"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toFixed` это метод чисел, а в полях объектов из JSON вы получаете строки. Нужно или работать со строкой при помощи регулярных выражений, или сначала преобразовывать строку в число, а потом форматировать при помощи `toFixed`.

Comment: а какой функцией преобразовать "27.70000" в число 27.70000 ?

Comment: Можно `Number.parseFloat()`. Конечные нули в дробной части будут убраны, но при необходимости будут опять добавлены после `toFixed`.

Comment: спасибо вот так заработало
parseFloat(data[i].sale).toFixed(2)